# Why does MS Example of GetDIBits create a new BITMAPINFOHEADER?

Tags: winapi, gdi

The Microsoft example of using `GetDIBits` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image) has to code below.  My question is why did they create a new `bi` item instead of just using the `bmpScreen` on the call to `GetDIBits` ?:

```
    // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP
    GetObject(hbmScreen,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmpScreen);
     
    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;
     
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;    
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;  
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
    // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
    // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize); 
    char *lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);    

    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into a buffer 
    // which is pointed to by lpbitmap.
    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Comment: This is `BITMAP bmpScreen` versus `BITMAPINFOHEADER bi`, you need both.

Answer (score 0):

[GetDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits#remarks):

> If the `lpvBits` parameter is a valid pointer, the first six members of
> the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure must be initialized to specify the size
> and format of the `DIB`. The scan lines must be aligned on a `DWORD`
> except for `RLE` compressed bitmaps.